# Icons on the desktop do not state the name of the file/directory?

Tags: icons

How do I fix the desktop icon which don't show the file/directory names they are associated with and has an icon size which is to small to be on the desktop?

I scanned through `unity-tweak-tool` but found no option option relevant to this.

*Ubuntu 13.04 it is.*

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently found the fix.

1. Open the `nautilus`/ file browser
2. File -> Preferences
3. Icon View Defaults
4. Default zoom level: `50%`(minimum)

I had previously set it to `33%` and hence the problem.